# In the user profile, make clear what the tag stats mean

Tags: feature-request

I look at my SO profile and I have strong difficulties understanding what's behind `score` and `posts %`.

The `title` (the text appearing when the mouse stays on the tag) isn't really helpful in understanding it either as there are no explanations but only more numbers, making it more confusing.

So would it be possible to make those stats clear about their meaning and intent directly in the profile, probably by adapting the `title` of each stat to show what it is instead of the general tag `title`?
[image: What is "score"? What is "posts %"?]

This image shows my confusion. What is "score"? What is "posts %"? My total number of questions is 130 (36 + 94); then why is my score only my answers? What is the score of an answer? What is the score of a question?

Answer (score 5):

The score of a post (question or answer) is upvotes - downvotes. The score for a tag appears to be the sum of all scores on *answers* in that tag. I have no idea why questions don't count towards the score. Possibly it uses the score for questions if you have more of those than answers in the tag.

Posts % only shows for your top tag, as far as I can see, and is simply the percentage of all of your posts that are in that tag. Taking my own profile as an example again, my top tag is [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), which I have 798 posts in. I have a total of 1184 posts. 798 / 1184 is roughly 0.6739, or 67.4%.

I imagine you're probably not the only one who doesn't necessarily understand what those numbers mean, though, so some explanation on the page might be useful.

Comment: My guess for why it only shows the non-cw answer score: Because that's the only score that counts towards a tag badge.

Comment: It's now clear. Thanks! But it's sad that it isn't more explicit (happily, this is a feature-request though).